# Elasticsearch merging documents in response

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having data in 3 indexes. I want to generate a invoice report using information from other indexes. For example the following are the sample document of each index

**Users index**

```
{
    "_id": "userId1",
    "name": "John"
}
```

**Invoice index**

```
{
    "_id": "invoiceId1",
    "userId": "userId1",
    "cost": "10000",
    "startdate": "",
    "enddate": ""
}
```

**Orders index**

```
{
    "_id": "orderId1",
    "userId": "userId1",
    "productName": "Mobile"
}
```

I want to generate a invoice report by combining information from these three indexes as follows

```
{
    "_id": "invoiceId1",
    "userName": "John",
    "productName": "Mobile",
    "cost": "10000",
    "startdate": "",
    "enddate": ""
}
```

How to write Elasticsearch query which returns response by combining information from other index documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You **cannot** do query-time joins in Elasticsearch and will need to denormalize your data in order to efficiently retrieve and group it.

---

Having said that, you could:

1. leverage the [multi-target syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) and query multiple indices at once
2. use an `OR` query on the `id` and `userId` -- since either of those is referenced *at least once* in *any* of your docs
3. and then trivially join your data through a map/reduce tool called [scripted metric aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)

*Quick side note: you won't be able to use the `_id` keyword inside your docs because it's reserved.*

Assuming your docs and indices are structured as follows:

```json
POST users_index/_doc
{"id":"userId1","name":"John"}

POST invoices_index/_doc
{"id":"invoiceId1","userId":"userId1","cost":"10000","startdate":"","enddate":""}

POST orders_index/_doc
{"id":"orderId1","userId":"userId1","productName":"Mobile"}
```

Here's how the scripted metric aggregation could look like:

```json
POST users_index,invoices_index,orders_index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id.keyword": {
              "value": "userId1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "userId.keyword": {
              "value": "userId1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_invoiceId": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.users = []; state.invoices = []; state.orders = []",
        "map_script": """
          def source = params._source;
          
          if (source.containsKey("name")) {
            // we're dealing with the users index
            state.users.add(source);
          } else if (source.containsKey("cost")) {
            // we're dealing with the invoices index
            state.invoices.add(source);
          } else if (source.containsKey("productName")) {
            // we're dealing with the orders index
            state.orders.add(source);
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          def non_empty_state = [:];
          for (entry in state.entrySet()) {
            if (entry != null && entry.getValue().length > 0) {
              non_empty_state[entry.getKey()] = entry.getValue();
            }
          }
          return non_empty_state;
        """,
        "reduce_script": """
          def final_invoices = [];
          
          def all_users = [];
          def all_invoices = [];
          def all_orders = [];
          
          // flatten all resources
          for (state in states) {
            for (kind_entry in state.entrySet()) {
              def map_kind = kind_entry.getKey();
              if (map_kind == "users") {
                all_users.addAll(kind_entry.getValue());
              } else if (map_kind == "invoices") {
                all_invoices.addAll(kind_entry.getValue());
              } else if (map_kind == "orders") {
                all_orders.addAll(kind_entry.getValue());
              } 
            }
          }
          
          // iterate the invoices and enrich them
          for (invoice_entry in all_invoices) {
            def invoiceId = invoice_entry.id;
            def userId = invoice_entry.userId;
            def userName = all_users.stream().filter(u -> u.id == userId).findFirst().get().name;
            def productName = all_orders.stream().filter(o -> o.userId == userId).findFirst().get().productName;
            def cost = invoice_entry.cost;
            def startdate = invoice_entry.startdate;
            def enddate = invoice_entry.enddate;
            
            final_invoices.add([
              'id': invoiceId,
              'userName': userName,
              'productName': productName,
              'cost': cost,
              'startdate': startdate,
              'enddate': enddate
            ]);
          }
          
          return final_invoices;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which'd return

```json
{
  ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_invoiceId" : {
      "value" : [
        {
          "cost" : "10000",
          "enddate" : "",
          "id" : "invoiceId1",
          "userName" : "John",
          "startdate" : "",
          "productName" : "Mobile"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Summing up, there are workarounds to achieve query-time joins. At the same time, scripts like this shouldn't be used in production because they could take forever.

Instead, this aggregation should be emulated outside of Elasticsearch after the query resolves and returns the index-specific hits.

*BTW — I set `size: 0` to return *just* the aggregation results so increase this parameter if you want to get some actual hits.*